# Sequelize query for overlapping events

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, sequelize.js

I am trying to make a findAll() query using Sequelize that does the following. I want to be able to enter a user's ID and search the Events table to find if any other users' events overlap with any of the chosen user's events. I want to make sure that the events overlap by at least 30 mins.

```
Events table
id     start                  end                    createdByUser
1      2020-08-17 05:00:00    2020-08-17 08:00:00    1
2      2020-08-17 06:00:00    2020-08-17 11:00:00    2
3      2020-08-17 07:00:00    2020-08-17 11:00:00    3
4      2020-08-18 12:00:00    2020-08-18 13:00:00    1
5      2020-08-18 12:50:00    2020-08-18 14:00:00    2
6      2020-08-18 09:00:00    2020-08-18 12:10:00    3
7      2020-08-18 12:00:00    2020-08-18 12:45:00    4
8      2020-08-18 15:00:00    2020-08-18 18:00:00    2
```

Example: I want to be able to say "look at all of User 1's events. See if any other users' events overlap with any of User 1's events by at least 30 mins." If the returned query data could somehow note which of User 1's events it overlaps with that would be even better! Something like the following:

```
{id: 2,
 start: 2020-08-17 06:00:00,
 end: 2020-08-17 11:00:00,
 createdByUser: 2,
 overlapWithEventID: 1
},
{id: 3,
 start: 2020-08-17 07:00:00,
 end: 2020-08-17 11:00:00,
 createdByUser: 3,
 overlapWithEventID: 1
},
{id: 7,
 start: 2020-08-18 12:00:00,
 end: 2020-08-18 12:45:00,
 createdByUser: 4,
 overlapWithEventID: 4
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help! This is a way more complex query than I am used to making.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.id overlapWithEventID
FROM events t1
JOIN events t2
WHERE t1.createdByUser = 1
  AND t2.createdByUser != 1
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, GREATEST(t1.start, t2.start), LEAST(t1.`end`, t2.`end`)) >= 30;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a51e532fa295ea18deed0639ab4d890)

Adjust to DBMS which you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. This definitely helps to orient my thinking for how to construct this query. I will update if I can successfully translate the query to Sequelize.

Comment: Akina, I found a way to call a raw MySQL command in Sequelize. It needs the second argument to prevent the result metadata being sent (which makes it appear as though the result is being sent twice). If you would like to add this to your answer I can accept it. `sequelize.query("SELECT t2.*, t1.id overlapWithEventID FROM events t1 JOIN events t2 WHERE t1.createdByUser = 1 AND t2.createdByUser != 1 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, GREATEST(t1.start, t2.start), LEAST(t1.`end`, t2.`end`)) >= 30;", {type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(function (result) {
      res.json(result);
    });`

Comment: @JarrettD5309 It's better to create self-answer with well-formatted code rather than the "noodles" in a comment.